# Does WooCommerce work ok with Toolbox wordpress child theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, woocommerce, toolbox

I'm going to be using WooCommerce and I need to figure out whether my best bet is to create a child theme of twentytwelve or to create a child theme of toolbox.

It's a difficult one to research due to the generic name of toolbox, so I was wondering if anyone had any toolbox/woocommerce experience and could maybe give that combination the green light.

Am fairly new to wordpress development, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'almost'.

I only ran into one issue - described and solved here: [woocommerce_cart shortcode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992944/woocommerce-cart-shortcode-not-working)