# woocommerce_cart shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, cart, shortcode, woocommerce

I am setting up Woocommerce, but when I click to go to my cart page, it shows...

Cart [woocommerce_cart] Edit

I've researched this but found nothing. I can confirm that I've had no other ecommerce plugin installed.

My theme is a Toolbox child theme. If I switch to the TwentyTwelve theme then the cart displays fine. What could be the problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I'm using WP v3.5.1, woocommerce v1.6.6 and my child theme is based on Toolbox v1.4.

Comment: Is it just the cart page that isn't working or all the shop pages as well?

Comment: The shop page is working fine. I think it could be a general shortcode problem because I have just created a very simple shortcode and the behaviour for this is exactly the same - my page just displays [foobar] for this also. It would seem that the Toolbox theme does not allow shortcodes!... What a great parent theme I chose! :(

Comment: I have checked this by disabling every single plugin (inc. WooCommerce) and still my foobar shortcode doesn't work. I think i will start another question for this...

Comment: Solution found!... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820190/enable-shortcodes-in-a-wordpress-theme :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly done by people who forget to switch to the HTML editor view. There are 2 modes, Visual and HTML. All shortcodes must be put in the HTML editor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the shortcode is auto-generated by the WooCommerce plugin. And it also works fine with the TwentyTwelve theme, so is there something missing from my child theme?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe look at what the Twelve theme is wrapping the shortcode in.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I've found the problem now, as mentioned above. Thanks for your help though.